# Why some PDF file don't work in PyPdf2 library?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pyttsx3

'''

```
PDFFILE=""
PDF_NAME=""
def pdf_btnClicked():
    global PDFFILE, PDF_NAME
    PathOfPDF = askopenfile()
    PDFFILE = PathOfPDF.name
    print(PDFFILE)
    if PDFFILE == "":
        return
    else:
        PDFLocation["text"] = PDFFILE
        # return PDFFILE
        # PDFFILE1=PDFFILE.get
        PDF_NAME= str(basename(normpath(PDFFILE)))
        print(PDF_NAME)
    
pages = 1
page_no = 1
pdfReader=''
def selectBtnClicked():
    global book
    global PDFFILE
    global pages
    global page_no
    global pdfReader
    print(PDFFILE)
    book = open(PDFFILE, 'rb')
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(book)
    pages = pdfReader.numPages
    print(pages)
    pages += 1
    page_no = [i for i in range(1, pages)]
    print(page_no)
    startfromLabel["values"] = page_no
    PDF_NAME_LABEL["text"]=PDF_NAME
    PDF_NAME_LABEL.place_forget()
    PDF_NAME_LABEL.pack(side=TOP, pady=20)
    startfromLabel.pack(side=TOP, pady=25)
    return page_no, pdfReader

def startBtnClicked():
    global pdfReader
    choice=startfromLabel.get()
    print(choice)
    speaker = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
    voices = speaker.getProperty('voices')
    speaker.setProperty('voice',voices[1].id)
    page = pdfReader.getPage(int(choice))
    text = page.extractText()
    speaker.say("Thank YOU SIR, SELECTING ME FOR THIS JOB!!!")
    print("Thank YOU SIR SELECTING ME FOR THIS JOB!!!")
    speaker.say(text)
    print("Started")
    root.update()
    speaker.runAndWait()
```

'''

I had made a `pdf describer` using `PyPdf2` in python. But I face a problem i.e it works in some pdf properly but in some other pdf file it doesn't work

problem example:-

it works properly on [oop.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EQDodyus2tVNTsG8bOuo44SHkg3FbhPe/view?usp=sharing) but it doesn't work on [the_portrait_of_mr._w.*h*.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k7Y0t8_kV1r1d0rz6u3CKHVP-s95blN9/view?usp=sharing)

Please help me to solve this problem

Thanking you

Comment: have you tried using a simple name for your pdf?

Comment: yes, sir, I had tried using rename to a simple name but it doesn't work

Comment: check this https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/437

Comment: This needs more focus. If the TTS part is not your problem, remove it from the question. Also be more specific than "doesn't work". And please add which version is pypdf you were using